# adding transport security to customBinding

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a customizedBinding where iam adding various bindings in the CreateBindingElemens method. Everything works great if I have the HttpTransportBindingElement, but as a next step i want to add transport security (ssl) to it, so i modified the code like this

```
        BindingElementCollection collection = new BindingElementCollection();
        collection.Add(httpPollingElement);
        if (session == SessionType.HttpSession)
        {
            collection.Add(httpSessionElement);
        }
        else
        {
            collection.Add(reliableSessionElement);
        }

        collection.Add(encodingElement);


        var securityBindingElement = new TransportSecurityBindingElement();
        collection.Add(securityBindingElement);
        collection.Add(httpTransportElement);
        return collection;
```

but iam getting an error saying *The security capabilities of binding 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding' do not match those of the generated runtime object. Most likely this means the binding contains a StreamSecurityBindingElement, but lacks a TransportBindingElement that supports Stream Security (such as TCP or Named Pipes). Either remove the unused StreamSecurityBindingElement or use a transport that supports this element.*

I can confirm that i dont have StramSecurityBindingElement in my configuration. Which security bindings should i be adding in order to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use ssl just add:

```
new HttpsTransportBindingElement()
```

instead of the http element.
no need to add security element when only transport security is used.

Comment: although this was not the issue, your post http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2010/03/wcf-security-capabilities-do-not-match.html did lead me to a solution, it was when security capabilities of the channel and binding do not match.